# combining two sorted rows so that the relative order of the objects in each row is preserved

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Need a little help.

Given 2 sorted rows $a_{1},..,a_{k} $ & $b_{1},...,b_{n} $ . We need to combine the 2 rows into one, $a_{2},..,a_{k} $ & $b_{1},...,b_{n} $ so that the elements in the 2 rows stay in the same order (so the element of the other row come in between). Element $a_{1}$ may be put anywhere along as it is not on the left hand side of $a_{2}$. How many different rows can be formed?

My work. Setting row $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ out you have $n+1$ places to put the $a_i$ elements, not counting $a_1$ so $k-1$ left are left, that is $(n+k)$ choose $n+1$. I just don't know how to deal with $a_1$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain your work rather than placing it in the comments where it might be missed.

Comment: Thanks have done

Answer (score 1):

> Two rows of objects $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ are combined to form a single row.  In how may ways can the objects be arranged if the relative order of the objects in each row is preserved?

Place the $n$ objects from the sequence $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ in a row.  This creates $n + 1$ spaces, $n - 1$ between successive objects and two at the ends of the row where objects from the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ can be placed.  Since the relative order of the terms in the sequence must be preserved, what matters is how many objects are placed in each space.

To illustrate, let $n = 3$ and $k = 4$.

$$\square b_1 \square b_2 \square b_3 \square$$

Then placing two objects in the first space, one in the second, and one in the fourth yields the sequence $a_1a_2b_1a_3b_2b_3a_4$.

Let $x_j$ denote the number of objects from the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ that are placed in the $j$th space.  Then
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{n + 1} = k \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of $n$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones.

For instance, the solution $(2, 1, 0, 1)$ to the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4$ that corresponds to the case $n = 3$ and $k = 4$ is represented by
$$1 1 + 1 + + 1$$
Notice that the addition signs correspond to the positions of the objects in the sequence $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$.

The number of solutions of equation 1 is 
$$\binom{k + n}{n}$$
since we must choose which $n$ of the $k + n$ symbols required for $k$ ones and $n$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

> Two rows of objects $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$ are combined to form a single row.  In how may ways can the objects be arranged if the relative order of the objects in each row is preserved except that $a_2$ must appear somewhere to the right of $a_1$?

We first rearrange the sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ so that $a_1$ is somewhere to the right of $a_2$ while the remaining terms of the sequence remain in the same relative order.  This can be done in $k - 1$ ways since $a_1$ must be placed to the immediate right of one of the other $k - 1$ elements in this sequence.  Fix the new order of the sequence.  Call the rearranged sequence $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$.

Now, apply the argument given above to the two sequences $c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_k$ and $b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n$.  The objects in the two rows can be combined into a single sequence in $\binom{k + n}{n}$ ways that preserves the relative order of the objects in each row.

Hence, there are 
$$(k - 1)\binom{k + n}{n}$$
ways to combine the two rows into a single row such that the relative order of the objects in each row is preserved except that $a_2$ is to the right of $a_1$.

Comment: thank you so much, a thousand apologies made a small typo in the question. namely element $a_{1}$ must be on the right hand side

Comment: You should not change a question after it has been answered.  Should the relative order of the other elements be preserved or do you merely require that $a_2$ be to the right of $a_1$?

Comment: my apologies, the relative order must be preserved except for $a_{1}$ which must come after $a_{2}$

Comment: Thank for the clarification.

Comment: I have added a solution to your revised question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start with an example.

The first sequence: $$\{3,6,8,12,18\}$$
The second sequence $$\{2,5,7,8,15\} $$
Start with $$\{3,6,8,12,18\}$$

Pick $2$ and fit it in $$\{3,6,8,12,18\}$$ to get $$\{2,3,6,8,12,18\}$$

Pick $5$ and fit it in  $$\{2,3,6,8,12,18\}$$ to get $$\{2,3,5,6,8,12,18\}$$
Pick $7$ and fit it in $$\{2,3,5,6,8,12,18\}$$ to get $$\{2,3,5,7,6,8,12,18\}$$ 
Pick $8$ and fit it in  $$\{2,3,5,67,8,12,18\}$$ to get  $$\{2,3,5,6,8,8,12,18\}$$

Pick $15$ and fit it in $$\{2,3,5,6,8,8,12,18\}$$ to get $$\{2,3,5,6,8,8,12,15,18\}$$ The final answer is $$\{2,3,5,6,8,8,12,15,18\}$$

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as placing $k - 1$ zeros and $n$ ones in a row (the zeros are the positions for $a_i$, the ones positions for $b_i$, in respective order). In all, it is $n + k - 1$ positions, of which you select $n$ for the $a_i$, i.e.
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{n}$$.